# What is the driving force of this reaction?

Tags: acid-base

I know that every reaction that occurs in a solution must have a driving force leading to the kicking out of some ions from the solution. These reactions include redox , double-displacements and acid/base. Now my question is if i react aqueous ammonia with aqueous hydrochloric acid what will be the driving force of this reaction?

I know that ammonium chloride is formed, but this salt is soluble in water so exists as aqueous ions. But for reactions in solutions some ions have to be removed, as a result creating a driving force for the reaction. Like in the case of Arrhenius acid-base reactions, the formation of liquid water is the driving force of the reaction.

Please help?

Comment: Why not think about reaction of gaseous NH3 and HCl - you get same thing, only not dissolved. Dissolving isn't considered a reaction, as you can get back the dissolved compound.

Answer (score -1):

"for reactions in solutions some ions have to be removed"

Suppose that you have 1 mole of hydronium ions(the counteranion of ammonium cations) and you add 1 mole of hydronium ions(countercation of chloride anions). Nearly all of them will react, resulting in formation of 2 moles of water, which has negligible for the sake of this question dissociation constant $K_w=10^{-14}$. So all the mentioned ions disappear.

Comment: Pardon me, but i completely didn't understand your answer. What are you trying to say exactly?

Comment: You have here exactly the case of Arrhenius acid-base reaction, which result in the formation of liquid water.

Comment: But my question does not include water as one of the products